# jquery: How can I select a hidden field?

Tags: jquery, element, hidden

I am using the jquery.raty script which does write a hidden field into my page like:

```
<input id="cancel-score" type="hidden" name="news_question_1" value="1">
```

I have this and many other form elements which I would like to monitor onChange.

I do this with:

```
$('#NewsletterSurveyForm').find(':input').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){....
```

Which works for all elements, but just not the hidden one.

Does anyone has an idea how to get its value?

Answer (score 8):

you can use following code,

```
$("input[type='hidden']").change(function(){......});
```

but change event doesn't fire when the value is programmatically changed. so you have to trigger it manually when the value changes.

```
$("#hiddenId").val("new value").change();
```

Comment: Hi, the change does happen through the rating script. And I don't know the value, it can be either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the hidden input supports the change event.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003053/does-html-hidden-control-have-any-events-like-onchange-or-something)

I think you should address this change trigger a level higher up.