# jQuery - Detect value change which use .val() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

We all know that use the `val()` will not trigger the `change` event, so we also use `.trigger('change')` behind the `val()`.

But the problem is that someone write the `val()` did't with `trigger()` and it's a external file that I can't edit it.

So, how can I detect value change through some code same like below:

```
$('.elem').on('change', function(){
   // do something
});
```

Comment: Why not add your own event listener for the element and then listen for the .trigger() event from there?

Comment: You might want to see the `watch` function :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers

Comment: @naota I make a demo after learn `watch`: http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/yfo7rrn8/. It works, but the watcher code must above the `val()` code and I set a `setInterval` to monitor the value change.It's a way, but I think it's not a elegant way. Or I'm using in a wrong way?

Comment: @Jiangshui OK, I saw your code on the jsfiddle. I guess this article might help you: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to override jquery's `val()`

```
var originalValFn = jQuery.fn.val;

jQuery.fn.val = function() {
    this.trigger('change');
    originalValFn.apply( this, arguments );
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2L7hohjz/js

Comment: You should probably check that arguments.length is greater than zero before triggering the event, otherwise simply reading a value with obj.val() will also trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var originalValFn = jQuery.fn.val;

function getErrorObject(){
    try { throw Error('') } catch(err) { return err; }
}

jQuery.fn.val = function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass( "element" )) {
        var err = getErrorObject();
        var caller_line = err.stack.split("\n")[4];
        var index = caller_line.indexOf("at ");
        var clean = caller_line.slice(index+2, caller_line.length);

        console.log(clean);
        console.log(arguments);
    }
    originalValFn.apply( this, arguments );
};
```

Comment: You should provide more context to your answer, just posting code isn't enough to explain why your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
     if (currentValue != previousValue)
     {
        // do something
     }
}, 500);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I commonly use the solution from this post to get around problems like this one:

[hidden input change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580761/hidden-input-change-event)

```
watchField('.elem', function(){
    //do some stuff here
});

function watchField(selector, callback) {
   var input = $(selector);
   var oldvalue = input.val();
   setInterval(function(){
      if (input.val()!=oldvalue){
          oldvalue = input.val();
          callback();
      }
   }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('.elem').on('keyUp', function(){
   // do something
});
```

or

```
$('.elem').on('lostFocus', function(){
   // do something
});
```

Thank you,

Comment: Use val() to change value, it will not trigger `change` event, and also not trigger `keyup` or `lostfocus` event, it not work.