# How to set value to hiddenfield and fire the OnValueChanged event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap `navbars` and for each tab I have a separate data to bind.So on tab change event I want to find the tab index and do the respective bindings.

For that I have taken asp `HiddenField` and had the `OnValueChanged` event

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" OnValueChanged="hdnField_ValueChanged" />
```

and setting the value in the `jquery` as following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                var activeTab1 = e.target;

                var activeTab = $(e.target).text(); // Get the name of active tab
                var previousTab = $(e.relatedTarget).text(); // Get the name of previous tab
                varTab = $("#myTab").tabs("option", "selected");
                document.getElementById("<%= hdnField.ClientID %>").value = varTab;   //Setting value for hiddenfield
                $(".active-tab span").html(activeTab);
                $(".previous-tab span").html(previousTab);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But the `OnValueChanged` event is not firing. How to set the index value for the hidden field

My html for navbars is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Menu</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">About</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionC">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HiddenField ValueChanged event only fires when the page is posted back to the server.  Once a trigger is posted back, it looks in viewstate to compare old vs new value, and if different, the ValueChanged event is raised.

If you are trying to trigger from the client, you can kind of force a change event like so: [hidden input change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580761/hidden-input-change-event)

Not sure if you want things running on client...

Comment: How to pass navbar index to hiddenfield in the same function which I mentioned above

Comment: If the code you have above sets the navbar, what you have will work fine.  But ValueChanged doesn't fire in the code behind until the page posts back to the server (as a POST operation).  Any navigation that triggers a GET request will not be a postback, and thus won't trigger the event.

Comment: What should I have to do inorder to fire to the code behind or what else events can be used to achieve the same

Comment: Anything on the server needs to post back to the server; you can trigger a __doPostBack(..); (read up on that for the exact arguments) but then you are triggering a postback every time someone clicks a nav item... I don't really know why you need ValueChanged in the first place, so if you could add that to your post that would help.  I would try to do whatever you can on the client.

Comment: I'm quiet new to this,actually I have written the code to run depending on the index number.So if I can get that index it is easy to perform.But finding difficulty to achieve this.If you better idea do help me with a sample program