# How do I trigger an onChange event for a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I want to fire an onChange event for hidden field, 
Most of the forums I've read suggests that onChange doesn't work for hidden fields, 
So is there a way around for that, something like Plan-B?

Comment: Can you give us your scenario?

Comment: For the hidden field how can you add onChange event..??for that also you need to depend on one of visible field right..??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In jQuery, you could trigger a custom event:

```
$("#hidden_input_id").trigger("special-change");
```

And you can listen with:

```
$("#hidden_input_id").on("special-change", function () {

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/byKak/

Reference:

- `.trigger()`: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: You can also trigger regular change event this way `$("#hidden_input_id").trigger("change");` and then regular `onChange` will trigger. Or using plain JS http://stackoverflow.com/a/1003155/758991