# alert immediately after text field get a value - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text field which is getting values from some process. I mean the user is not giving any input to this text field directly! Now my problem is that I want the value of that text field immediately after it changes.
I tried

`oninput` and `onchange`

Here is the [bin](http://jsbin.com/neh/1/edit?html,output) of what I have tried.
Both events want to focus of that area
please tell me is there any way to achieve this

Comment: When said other process changes the input, have it trigger the input's change event.

Comment: This is not a jQuery question. His JS Bin has no jQuery: it is vanilla

Comment: You can find a your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601556/how-do-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-for-a-hidden-field

hope it can help you

Comment: @thelambdaC yes u r rite bt i meant that you can give me jquery solution too :)

Comment: @Null I have updated my answer to include both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Kevin B suggested, trigger the event manually from the process that changes 'a'.

Essentially, on button click:

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
a.value = value;
a.onchange();
```

A jQuery solution is here: http://jsbin.com/vozilevu/2

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    $('#a').val('a').change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to trigger a change event each time a character is entered, you can use something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="alert( document.getElementById('a').value )">
```

Comment: This will not work for his situation: the button's `onclick` event is changing the value. The idea is he wants a programmatic change of value, not user input.