# How to run function when input is disabled or reenabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

Is there some way to run a function when a input is disabled/enabled from another part of the code, for example when this code is run:

```
$('#myinput').prop('disabled', true);
```

I want another part of the code to be notified about this, but without making it dependent on the other part. Something similar to how "change" event works. But there's no "disabled" event...

Comment: Trigger that event to notify about update;

Comment: By the way what you want to do in this way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that will trigger when those properties are changed.

You can do this some other way.

Set hidden field for this enable disabled value like 1 / 0

```
$("#hiddenid").trigger("hiddenidchange");


$("#hiddenid").on("hiddenidchange", function () {

});
```

refer [How do I trigger an onChange event for a hidden field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601556/how-do-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-for-a-hidden-field)

Answer (score 0):

You can call notification trigger in the next line with an if statement

```
document.getElementById("email").disabled=true;
if(document.getElementById("email").disabled == true)
 {
   alert("Notifying..");
   //call the trigger function
 }
```