# javascript hide form field based on value of another form field

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following two fields on an HTML form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Valid" id="Valid" value="True">

<input type="text" id="Address">
```

I need a JavaScript method that will disable the `address` input if the value of the `valid` input is true.

What can I use to do this, please?

I think I need a way of toggling `disabled` on the `Address` input form.

Comment: is there any reason why you save the validation result to a hidden HTML element?

Comment: it's not a validation result. it's a just a field whose value is determined from a back end process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a "onchange"-event, which triggers when the value of that hidden input changes. Here is an example of that: [Does HTML Hidden control have any events? Like onchange or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003053/does-html-hidden-control-have-any-events-like-onchange-or-something)

But from reading the comments, that wasn't needed at all :-)

What is needed, is a logic which runs on page-load.
Your function only needs to add the disabled-attribute to the field, when the valid-value is true.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Valid" id="Valid" value="True">


<script>
// Define your function
function yourfunc() {
    var validValue = document.getElementById("Valid").getAttribute('value');
    if(validValue == 'True') {
        document.getElementById("Address").setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
}
yourfunc(); // Call the function: is important, otherwise your code will never be run.
</script>
```

To remove the disabled-property again, you can check this thread: [.setAttribute("disabled", false); changes editable attribute to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526601/setattributedisabled-false-changes-editable-attribute-to-false)

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly. The value of `valid` won't change. It is being worked out backend, and by the time the page loads the value will be fixed at true or false.

Comment: When should the value of valid change? You didn't specify anything yet for the change of #Valid

Comment: at the point when the page loads the valid will be true or false and will stay that way. for the sake of this question, let's say it's always true. thanks

Comment: oh - that's a completly different use case; i edited my answer accordingly to this information. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a javascript method that will disable the address input if the value of the valid input is true.

Based on this line alone, the below code should work

```js
const validInput = document.querySelector('#Valid');
const addressInput = document.querySelector('#Address')

const toggleAddress = () => {
    const inputVal = validInput.value;
    
    if(inputVal === 'True') {
            addressInput.disabled = true
    }
}

toggleAddress()
```

Although your question doesn't say when it should be enabled.

Comment: thanks for this. this would work for me - i have marked the first response as the answer as that is the one i have used.